# Div with margin and width breaks in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have the following markup:

```css
.content__wrapper {
  min-height: 325px;
}

.content__img {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tab__content {
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

blockquote {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="content__wrapper d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">

  <div class="content__img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/360/360/any);">
    <div class="tab__content ">
      <div class="content__content">
        <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

In Chrome, Firefox etc, the div is loading file, like so:

[image]

However, in IE11, the image is showing up really small and the width on `.tab__content` is being ignored (it looks like it's 100% width, which makes it create a horizontal scrollbar).

Any ideas why this behaviour comes about?

Comment: I don't see a CSS definition for `content__content`. Also, a screenshot from IE would help.

Comment: not the cause of the issue but your margin auto overrides your margin left so you can just delete that

Comment: there's one more issue in your CSS code in the `.tab__content` class you're setting `margin-left: 30%;` then you're overriding it with `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the min-height content__wrapper to content__img..

**css**

```
.content__img {
  min-height: 325px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer ignores `min-height` when no `height` is set.

And this behaviour too: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=min-height)

> In Internet Explorer 10 and 11, a min-height declaration on a column-direction flex container doesn't apply to the container's flex items.

A little hack could be:

```
.content__wrapper {
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 325px;
}
```

```css
.content__wrapper {
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 325px;
}

.content__img {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tab__content {
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

blockquote {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="content__wrapper d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">

    <div class="content__img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/360/360/any);">
        <div class="tab__content ">
            <div class="content__content">
                <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```